# using vectors to proof 3 points are on the same line

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

There are three vectors $\vec{OA}=u+2v-w, \ \vec{OB}=-2u+v , \ \vec{OC}=-5u+w$
such that $u,v,w$ are also vectors.
I need to prove that A,B,C are on the same line.
I know that $\vec{OA}, \vec{OB},\vec{OC}$ are not linearly independent because the rank of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&-5\\2&1&0\\-1&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$ is 2, but I have no idea how does it help me.
I'll be grateful for help!

Comment: Hint: Calculate the cross product $(B-A)\times (C-A)$.

Comment: If the vectors are linearly dependent then they are a scalar multiple of one another meaning they are collinear meaning they lie on the same line

Comment: @Aname The vectors $e_1,e_2,$ and $e_1+e_2$ are linearly dependent but no vector is a scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: You only need to show that $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ are scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: @MatthewH do you mean (OB-OA)x(OC-OA)?

Comment: @trancelocation Thanks, it worked!

Comment: @killer333ii Very much welcome. :-)